# How do I split a cookie using php

Tags: php, cookies, split

I have a cookie which I'm trying to split. The cookie is in this format:

key = val1,val2,val3  (where each value is separated by commas)

is there a way for me to split this in a loop so that I can directly access val3?

I've tried using the explode() function with no success.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_COOKIE); $i++)
{
    $ind = key($_COOKIE);
    $data = $_COOKIE[$ind];

    //I try and slit the cookie here
    $cookie_temp = explode(",",$_COOKIE[$ind]);

    //Here is where I wanted to display Val3 from the cookie
    print $cookie_temp[2];

    next($_COOKIE);
}
```

my code works fine but I then end up with all my Val3 in a large array. For example, my val3's are numbers and they get put in an array. Can I split this even further?

Comment: "I have a cookie which I'm trying to split." Can I have a piece?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are looping because you have multiple comma-separated cookie key/value groups, use a `foreach()` instead and with `list()` you can retrieve the third value with a direct assignment.

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key=>$value) {
  list($v1, $v2, $v3) = explode("," $value);
  echo $v3;
}
```

If you have only one cookie value to access, there is no need for the loop, and you can directly call `explode(",", $_COOKIE['key'])`

PHP 5.4 allows array dereferencing, whereby you can directly access the array element off of the `explode()` call, but this won't work in earlier PHP versions.

```
echo explode(",", $_COOKIE['key'])[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'm hoping you know the name of the cookie you're trying to get the value of. Let's call it `mycookie` in the rest of my answer.

Second, just scrap the whole loop thing and just access `$_COOKIE['mycookie']` directly.

Then, you can now call `explode(",",$_COOKIE['mycookie'])` to get the separate values.

Next, just get index 2 with `[2]` as you are in your current code.

As a shortcut, if the second one is the only one you need:

```
list(,,$val) = explode(",",$_COOKIE['mycookie']);
```